# Brother-in-law received a refusal for a US visa twice under 214b. Needs to visit father critically ill

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas

My brother-in-law received a refusal for a US visa twice under 214b. He needs to visit his father who got critically ill (brain surgery) and  has been in ICU for more than 40 days. He applied for a visa after 30 days during these difficult times.

What should be the next steps?

1. Brother-in-law is not married, doesn't have a good job, but has some properties.
2. He has a letter from hospital.

Comment: What nationality is the brother-in-law? Might help to know father's immigration status in the USA, too.

Comment: From India got notifications about this just now sorry for delayed response

Answer (score 1):

[Humanitarian or Significant Public Benefit Parole for Individuals Outside the United States](https://www.uscis.gov/humanitarian/humanitarian-or-significant-public-benefit-parole-individuals-outside-united-states)

> Individuals who are outside of the United States may be able to
>   request parole into the United States based on humanitarian or
>   significant public benefit reasons.
>
> **Step 1: Filing of Parole Request**
>
> The petitioner files the following at the USCIS Lockbox in Dallas:
>
> Form I-131, Application for Travel Document
>
> Form I-134, Affidavit of Support (PDF, 461 KB)
>
> Supporting documentation
>
> The filing fee (or Form> I-912, Request for Fee Waiver)
>
> The Lockbox sends the parole request to USCIS International Operations
>   Division (USCIS-IO) in Washington, D.C.
>
> Step 2: USCIS Reviews the Request for Urgency (Triage)
>
> Step 3: USCIS Officer Makes a Decision
>
> Step 4: Supervisor Reviews the Decision
>
> Step 5: USCIS Provides Notification of the Decision
>
> **Step 6: Issuance of Travel Documents and Parole into the United States
>   (Approvals Only)**
>
> If a request is authorized, the approval notice will inform the
>   beneficiary that he or she must complete a Form DS-160, Application
>   for a Nonimmigrant Visa, and appear for an appointment with the
>   Department of State consular section to verify their identity and
>   collect biometrics for additional security vetting. All beneficiaries
>   14 years and older must provide biometrics. If no derogatory
>   information or new identity information is identified during vetting,
>   the U. S. Consulate issues a document referred to as a boarding foil
>   that allows the beneficiary to travel to the United States within 30
>   days of it being issued.  Issuance of a boarding foil does not
>   guarantee parole but allows the beneficiary to proceed to Step 7
>   below.
>
> **> Step 7: Customs and Border Protection (CBP) Paroles into the United
>   States (Approvals Only)**
>
> A CBP officer inspects the beneficiary at the port of entry. If CBP
>   paroles the beneficiary, CBP will issue the parolee an I-94,
>   Arrival/Departure Record, documenting the length of their parole
>   period. The parole period begins when CBP paroles the beneficiary at
>   the port of entry. After arriving in the United States, the parolee
>   may request employment Form I-765, Application for Employment
>   Authorization.
>
> If you are represented, you must include a completed Form G-28, Notice
>   of Entry of Appearance as Attorney or Representative, for USCIS to
>   communicate with your attorney or representative.
>
> Submitting Evidence
>
> The petitioner must show, through the parole request and supporting
>   evidence, that the beneficiary qualifies for parole and merits a
>   favorable exercise of discretion. Submitting all relevant supporting
>   evidence will avoid delays. A USCIS officer may issue a Request for
>   Evidence (RFE) to seek additional information. In addition to the Form
>   I-131, Application for Travel Document, Form I-134, Affidavit of
>   Support (PDF, 461 KB), and the filing fee or request for fee waiver,
>   the petitioner should submit the following evidence to support their
>   parole request:
>
> Detailed explanation of the reasons why the petitioner is requesting
>   parole;
>
> Detailed explanation of the length of time for which the beneficiary
>   needs parole;
>
> Detailed explanation of why the beneficiary cannot obtain a U.S.
>   nonimmigrant or immigrant visa from the U.S. Department of State
>   including:
>
> -When and where the beneficiary attempted to obtain visas, if applicable;
>   -If a visa application was denied, include a copy of the denial letter; and
>   -If applicable, a detailed explanation of the reasons why the beneficiary cannot obtain any required waiver of inadmissibility and a
>   copy of any denial letter received.